# Drawing sunpath in 3D using Cesium

Tags: 3d, cesiumjs

I want to draw the sunpath in 3D using latitude, longitude and datetime as shown in
[Sunpath](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4AEbT.jpg). Depending on the location and time information, I've got the sun's azimuth and altitude values. How should I use Cesium to achieve this?

How should I proceed? 
Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

The logical approach would be to calculate the sun position as azimuth and height for different dates and times to get the solar path lines for each month. This is different for every location and depending on the timestamp.

First include some dependancies that will help with sun position calculation and with date and time formats in javascript as follows:

1. Include [suncalc.js](https://github.com/mourner/suncalc) in your code (It's open source and BSD-2 lisenced)
2. Include [moment.js](https://github.com/moment/moment/) in your code (It's open source and MIT lisenced)

Second you need a library to display objects in 3d. So include a library that can help you with that:

1. Include [three.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/) in your code (It's open source and MIT lisenced)

After that make a scene in three.js where you can draw 3d objects (I am not posting that code, because you can set a three.js scene rather easilly).

You will draw a line, as a sun orbit, for each month based on the sun position of every hour/minutes or so. You can do so by looping for the months and for every hour or every minute of the hour (to get a better result):

```
var sunpathline = new THREE.Geometry();
var sunpathmat = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
    color : 0xffbf00
});

var Latitude = 37;//set your latitude
var Longitude = 22;//set your longitude
var distance = 50; //this is the scale of the 3d chart (as a distance from (0,0,0)
var d = new Date();//date or you call moment() with no parameters
var y = d.getFullYear();//current year ex 2021
var day;//variable to hold the date
var tempPosition;//variable to hold the position in x,y,z

for(var m = 1; m < 13; m++) {//loop for each month
    
    day = moment(y+"-01-01", "YYYY-MM-DD");//get a date object
    day= day.add(m, 'months');//add one month
    
    for(var s = 0; s <= 60; s++) {//loop for 60 minutes
                                        
        //add minutes to date
        day.add(s, 'minutes');
        //format date for suncalc use
        day.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
        
        //get sun position of the sun with Suncalc
        var pos = SunCalc.getPosition(day, Latitude, Longitude);
        //azimuth and altitude of the sun from suncalc
        var azimuth = pos.azimuth * distance;
        var altitude = pos.altitude * distance;
        
        //calculate positions as x,y,z coordinates for three.js
        //z is rather easy because its only a mater of sin of the angle
        var lightZ = distance * Math.sin(altitude * (Math.PI / 180));

        //x and y is more complex as you get the distance angle first
        var dist = distance * Math.cos(altitude * (Math.PI / 180));
        //then you get a sin or cos for x, y parameters
        var lightX = -dist * Math.sin(azimuth * (Math.PI / 180));
        var lightY = -dist * Math.cos(azimuth * (Math.PI / 180));
        tempPosition = [lightX, lightY, lightZ];
        
        //if z dimension to the top positive or rather positive             
        if(tempPosition[2]>-10){
            sunPoints.push(tempPosition);
            //(y, z, x) = (y to the depth, z to the top, x to the right)
            //I am using a three.js vector here
            sunpathline.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(tempPosition[1], tempPosition[2], tempPosition[0]));
        }else{
            sunPoints.push([0,0,0]);
            sunpathline.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3([0,0,0]));
        }
    }//for minutes loop
}//for months loop

//name your line and apply material
Sunpath = new THREE.Line(sunpathline, sunpathmat);
//add it to your scene
scene.add(Sunpath);
```

You can also do this for analema lines, looping for every hour and inside every hour, looping for each month.

The image you posted as an example is then the top of your scene. A polar sun chart is a y section of your three.js scene.

Things to keep in mind. Adding months in moment is safe because if day is Jan-31 and add one month you get Feb-28. But adding time to moment changes the timezone because you want to get exact results in time. For example adding time to UTC+0200 can change time to UTC+0300 so either set the timezone globally or check you get the same utc in moment object.

Comment: is this an answer?